# Добавление строк в .xls файл

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi

Есть такой код, он работает для редактирования существующих данных. Вопрос в том, как добавить новую строку в .xls файл. Так как обращение к пустой ячейке генерирует ошибку `NullPointerException`.

```
public class UpdateExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   File file = new File("fileName");
   // Read XSL file
   FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

   // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

   // Get first sheet from the workbook
   HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
   cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() * 2);

   inputStream.close();

   // Write File
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю что `NullPointerException` падает в

```
cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() * 2);
```

добавьте проверку

```
if (cell == null) {
    cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2);
}
```

Comment: 'NullPointerException ' генерируется в этой строчке 'HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);'. Как можно это обойти??

Comment: Я так понял, что sheet.getRow(1) == null, тогда, попробуйте так  Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
if (row == null) {
    row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
}

Comment: В этом случае генерируется ошибка 'NotOLE2FileException' и фаил ломается. Обошел проблему костылем, скопировав инфу в новый xls и записав его под тем же именем. В новом xls можно работать. Спасибо за помощь)))

Comment: можно попробовать обойтись без костылей    if (file.getName().endsWith(".xls")) {
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
   }
   else if (file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
      workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   }

Comment: Я попытался выполнить данный код. Но по какой то причине он ломает xls файл.